# Unable to create tables in mysql in broadleaf installation

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, broadleaf-commerce

I am trying to set up local broadleaf demo site environment with MySQL database connected to it. I have configured all the MySQL connections by following the documentation.

I ran the following commands in demo site directory
`mvn clean install` and then in the admin directory when I run the command `mvn spring-boot:run` I am getting the below exceptions. Also few of the tables are not created and there is an error with MySQL syntax. Please see the below errors. I checked the local database the tables are created. But the tables mentioned in the error doesn't exists in the database.

This is the initial exception

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown table 'system_sequences' in information_schema
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1218) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
```

Afterwards some tables are unable to create becuase of syntax error

```
o.h.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache    : HHH000248: Starting query cache at region: org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache
org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table BLC_CATEGORY (CATEGORY_ID bigint not null, ACTIVE_END_DATE timestamp, ACTIVE_START_DATE timestamp, ARCHIVED char(255), DESCRIPTION varchar(255), DISPLAY_TEMPLATE varchar(255), EXTERNAL_ID varchar(255), FULFILLMENT_TYPE varchar(255), INVENTORY_TYPE varchar(255), LONG_DESCRIPTION longvarchar, META_DESC varchar(255), META_TITLE varchar(255), NAME varchar(255) not null, OVERRIDE_GENERATED_URL boolean, PRODUCT_DESC_PATTERN_OVERRIDE varchar(255), PRODUCT_TITLE_PATTERN_OVERRIDE varchar(255), ROOT_DISPLAY_ORDER numeric, TAX_CODE varchar(255), URL varchar(255), URL_KEY varchar(255), DEFAULT_PARENT_CATEGORY_ID bigint, primary key (CATEGORY_ID))
 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'longvarchar, META_DESC varchar(255), META_TITLE varchar(255), NAME varchar(255) ' at line 1
 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table BLC_CMS_MENU_ITEM (MENU_ITEM_ID bigint not null, ACTION_URL varchar(255), ALT_TEXT varchar(255), CUSTOM_HTML longvarchar, LABEL varchar(255), SEQUENCE numeric, MENU_ITEM_TYPE varchar(255), MEDIA_ID bigint, LINKED_MENU_ID bigint, LINKED_PAGE_ID bigint, PARENT_MENU_ID bigint, primary key (MENU_ITEM_ID))
 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'longvarchar, LABEL varchar(255), SEQUENCE numeric, MENU_ITEM_TYPE varchar(255), ' at line 1
 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table BLC_CUSTOMER_PAYMENT_FIELDS (CUSTOMER_PAYMENT_ID bigint not null, FIELD_VALUE longvarchar, FIELD_NAME varchar(255) not null, primary key (CUSTOMER_PAYMENT_ID, FIELD_NAME))
 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'longvarchar, FIELD_NAME varchar(255) not null, primary key (CUSTOMER_PAYMENT_ID,' at line 1
```

The other exception as shown below

```
org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.ImportScriptException: Error during statement execution (file: 'config/bc/sql/demo/load_catalog_data.sql'): INSERT INTO BLC_CATEGORY (CATEGORY_ID,DESCRIPTION,NAME,URL,ACTIVE_START_DATE,DISPLAY_TEMPLATE,ROOT_DISPLAY_ORDER, OVERRIDE_GENERATED_URL) VALUES (2001,'Home','Home','/',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'layout/homepage', -5.000000, FALSE)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.importScript(SchemaExport.java:451) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.11.Final.jar:4.1.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:378) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.11.Final.jar:4.1.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:304) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.11.Final.jar:4.1.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:293) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.11.Final.jar:4.1.11.Final]

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'broadleaf.blc_category' doesn't exist
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1355) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2128) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
```

At the end, I see this exception followed by build failure

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Table 'broadleaf.blc_sku_fee' doesn't exist; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Table 'broadleaf.blc_sku_fee' doesn't exist
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261) ~[spring-orm-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244) ~[spring-orm-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:525) ~[spring-orm-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:209) ~[spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
```

Can someone point me in a right direction to get this build sucessful?

Answer (score 0):

This log message is the key:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown table 'system_sequences' in information_schema

`system_sequences` is an HSQL-specific thing. This usually means that Hibernate is still configured to utilize the HSQL dialect.

The docs on [switching to MySQL](https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/key-aspects-and-configuration/database-configuration/mysql) indicate making sure that you switch this out with the MySQL5InnoDBDialect:

```
blPU.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
blSecurePU.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
blCMSStorage.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```